# Thumbnail for previously uploaded Videos retrieved from to Firebase

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a thumbnail from videos. The print ("Thumbnail generated successfully") is getting printed in the console but the actual video messages are not changing from the placeholder to the thumbnail.

The videos are being uploaded to Firebase storage through a StorageManager file that is being called in the last code below.

Here is my function:

```
func generateThumbnail(for videoUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
       DispatchQueue.global().async {
           let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl)
           let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
           imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
           
           let time = CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 60) // Get thumbnail at 1 second
           do {
               let cgImage = try imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: time, actualTime: nil)
               let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   completion(thumbnail)
                   print("Thumbnail generated successfully")
               }
           } catch {
               print("Error generating thumbnail: \(error)")
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   completion(nil)
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Here is where the function gets called and how the videos are created and uploaded to Firebase Storage.

```
if let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {
            let fileName = "photo_message_" + messageId.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "-") + ".mov"
            
            generateThumbnail(for: videoUrl) { [weak self] thumbnailImage in
                if let thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage {
            
                    //Upload Video
                    StorageManager.shared.uploadMessageVideo(with: videoUrl, fileName: fileName, completion: { [weak self] result in
                        guard let strongSelf = self else {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let urlString):
                            //Ready to send message
                            print("Uploaded Message Video: \(urlString)")
                            
                            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            let media = Media(url: url,
                                              image: nil,
                                              placeholderImage: thumbnailImage,
                                              size: .zero)
                            
                            let message = Message(sender: selfSender,
                                                  messageId: messageId,
                                                  sentDate: Date(),
                                                  kind: .video(media))
                            
                            DatabaseManager.shared.sendMessage(to: conversationId, otherUserEmail: strongSelf.otherUserEmail, name: name, newMessage: message, completion: { success in
                                if success {
                                    print ("Sent Video Message")
                                } else {
                                    print("Failed to send photo messsage")
                                }
                            })
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("message video upload error: \(error)")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What messages? You haven't shown enough code to represent the issue

Comment: Have you tried showing the image locally (or even printing the actual data -- is it non-nil?) to check that what you expect to be there is there?

Comment: You need to update your question with more details about what the code is doing and what is should be doing. Clarify what your issue is.

Comment: Hi, thank you guys for your help. I have to rephrase the question better. 
The application works perfectly. I can send and receive videos and photos in a real-time chat and view them. 
The issue comes when trying to have a thumbnail for the preview of the videos in the chat. I am just seeing a placeholder instead of the actual thumbnail.